# XAMPP cant open PHP file

Tags: xampp

I have installed XAMPP in my C Drive. When I visit `localhost`, i can see the default XAMPP landing page. However I cannot get XAMPP to open any PHP file.

What am i doing wrong?

Below is my system configuration

```
    Windows 10
    InstalledXAMPP3.2.4;
    ApcheRunning;
    MySqlRunning;
    
    BrowserOpenhttp://localhost/dashboard/perfectly;
    BrowserOpenshttp://localhost/test.htmlperfectly;
    
    BrowserCANTOpenhttp://localhost/test/test.html;
    BrowserCANTOpenhttp://localhost/test/;
    
    Error:TherequestedURLwasnotfoundonthisserver.
    
    
    BrowserCANTOpenhttp://localhost/test/test.html;
    BrowserCANTOpenhttp://localhost/test/;
    
    Error:TherequestedURLwasnotfoundonthisserver.
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Make sure you place your project files inside the "htdocs" folder. In your case the 'test' folder should reside in 'htdocs'.

location: xampp/htdocs

Comment: You needn't change it. Just go ti htdocs...delete all the default xampp files present there, and finally copy your project files there and you're good to go.